# How to parse a text file (CSV) into haskell so I can operate on it?

Tags: haskell

I have a flat text file with the following format:

```
ID|COUNT|Desc
1|100|Something
2|100|More
1|15|Whatever
```

I need to load this into Haskell so that I can perform some operations (in the case a GROUP-BY ID and SUM COUNT) and I am looking for ways to do it - one thing I cannot use any additional modules/packages (this is a school project - trying to figure it out with whatever is built-in).

I was doing some research and found Text.CSV as an option but can't really understand how it works (can't find any examples either - which is scary) - before I spend to much time there wondering if that is even the right approach - any suggestions, ideas, or examples would be much appreciated.

Keep me in mind that however it get stored I will have to process the data afterwards somehow.

---

I am trying this approach now:

```
main::IO()
main = do
       dbSales <- readFile "la.txt"
       let sales = lines dbSales
       (result, x, y) <- mapify sales
       print result

mapify :: [String] -> Map Int Int
mapify = Prelude.foldr (\s m -> let (id:count:desc) = (splitWhen (=='|') s)
                                    i = read id
                                    c = read count
                                 in insertWith (+) i c m) empty
```

However it complains about the line where I call mapify:

```
Couldn't match type `Map Int' with `IO'
Expected type: IO Int
  Actual type: Map Int Int
```

---

Trying with a new input file and not sure why but getting errors - if I use the following input:

```
ID1|ID2|DATE|SUM
0|0|07/13/2014/100
0|1|07/13/2014/101
0|2|07/13/2014/102
1|0|07/13/2014/100
```

And now instead I am trying to group on ID2 and SUM (instead od ID and COUNT from the previous example):

```
mapify :: [String] -> Map Int Int
mapify = Prelude.foldr (\s m -> let (id1:id2:date:sum) = (splitWhen (=='|') s)
                                    i = read id1
                                    j = read id2
                                    k = read date
                                    c = read sum
                                  in insertWith (+) j c m) empty
```

But no matter what I try I keep getting errors like this:

```
Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
Expected type: String
  Actual type: [[Char]]
In the first argument of `read', namely `sum'
In the expression: read sum
In an equation for `c': c = read sum
```

Comment: You can use `Data.List.Split` to break up your string aroung pipes and then read the first two fields into your data type. But it would probably be easier to use a Data.Map from ids to counts instead of your own collection of `ITEM`s.

Comment: @genisage how could you get this into a Datap.Map?

Comment: mapify doesn't return a triple, and you're not using `x` or `y` for anything, so maybe replace `(result, x, y)` with just `result`

Comment: If I change that line to `let result = mapify sales`, it compiles for me.

Comment: If you're not allowed to use additional modules, how is it OK to use Data.Map? It's a very good choice, but are you allowed to use it?

Comment: @AndrewC I was told I could use built-in modules like MAP,LIST,ARRAY, nothing that is 3rd party or requires any additional downloads or stuff

Comment: @genisage compiles but when I run main I get the following error: 'fromList *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse'

Comment: `let sales = tail (lines dbSales)` instead of just `lines dbSales` will probably fix it.

Comment: @genisage I owe you big time ... thanks for all the help with the proof of concept - going to scale this up now based on your idea - very much appreciated

Comment: Happy to help. Good luck with the rest of it.

Comment: @genisage trying to figure out why changing the input file makes such a big impact - I take a new input which looks like this ID1|ID2|DATE|SUM and I can't get this to work anymore - I changed the LET line to be 'let (id1:id2:date:sum)' and modified the rest but I get errors (give me 10 seconds I'll update the original post with exact code) - any clues?

Comment: It's because `sum` is a list of all of the strings left in your list of strings. make it `(id1:id2:date:sum:rest)`. Or better yet, since you're not using `i` or `k` make it `(_:id2:_:sum:rest)` and get rid of the unecessary `read`s. (Even though `sum` is the last field, it still ends up being a list of one string, and read doesn't operate on lists of lists.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapify :: [String] -> Map Int Int
mapify = foldr (\s m -> let (id:count:desc) = (splitWhen (=='|') s)
                            i = read id :: Int
                            c = read count :: Int
                        in insertWith (+) i c m) empty
```

I think that should be pretty much what you want. It reads the first two values of each string into Ints, then insertWith adds the id to the map if it's not there, or increases the current count if it is. As it is it will crash with malformed data, so you might want to fix that, and it needs `Data.List.Split` and `Data.Map`

Comment: First, love the name (mapify). So trying to test it out here, I need to open my file and then iterate over it line-by-line and for each line call mapify right?

Comment: I mean, I have two ways of doing this initial part, I could use readFile and then lines to break in into a list of lines, or I need to write some nasty loop and do something with hGetLine and hIsEOF

Comment: Ambiguous occurrence 'foldr'. It could refer to either 'Prelude.foldr' or 'Data.Map.foldr'.

Comment: It's supposed to be Prelude's

Comment: You have a couple options, you can `import Data.Map hiding (foldr)`, you can type `Prelude.foldr`, or you can `import qualified Data.Map as M` and then put `M.` in front of everything from Map. It happened because you have access to two `foldr`'s from different libraries and haskell wants you to tell it which one to use.

Comment: Ok - now trying to test this out and as always (real newb with Haskell) always have issues with returns - I have added my updated code to the post so you can see it correctly - as well as the error... any clues?

Comment: If you get a chance, take a look at my edit, trying to see why I can't change the input file without causing some odd errors.